# how to get horizontal depth of a node?

Tags: xml, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

note i made up the term horizontal depth to measure the sub-dimension of a node within a tree.

so imagine a  which would have xpath something like /html/table/tbody/tr/td, and "horizontal depth" of 5

i am trying to see if there is a way to identify and select elements based on this horizontal depth.

how can i find the maximum depth ?

Comment: how is "horizontal depth" different from the intuitive definition of depth in a tree?

Comment: no difference. i didnt want to confuse between vertical and horizontal depth.

Comment: I think you should have given some example XML and the expected resultset.

Comment: Now you've got me interested. What *is* the difference between between "vertical" and "horizontal" depth?

Answer (score 4):

If you need all the nodes with depth >= 5:

```
/*/*/*/*//*
```

And if you need all the nodes with depth == 5:

```
/*/*/*/*/*
```

Actually, there is a XPath function `count`, which you can combine with `ancestor` axis:

```
//*[count(ancestor::*) >= 4]
```

Comment: Vertical or horizontal?

Just kidding, I don't know using XPath (brief googling with no luck). But you can simply take all the nodes with XPath, and then in Ruby find the one with the largest number of ancestors.

Answer (score 2):

I think that "vertical depth" and "horizontal depth" are ambiguous.  Is there any reason not to use the axis terminology that already exists in XPath, and refer to "number of ancestors" and "number of preceding siblings"?  It's slightly more verbose, but not much, and a) it's unambiguous and b) the terms map onto `count(ancestor::*)` and `count(preceding-sibling::*)`.

Comment: how can i get the maximum depth of the tree ?

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but here we go:

First, a function for moving "horizontally" from an element:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def go_up(element):
    "Returns parent element of <element>."
    if element.tag_name == "body":
        return element
    else:
        old_e = element.tag_name
        parent = element.find_element(By.XPATH, "..")
        new_e = parent.tag_name
        #print("{} ^ {}".format(old_e, new_e))
        return parent
```

Then a function for walking from an element to the body node, counting the steps:

```
def ancestors_to_root(element):
    """
    Returns <int> of number of steps <element> is from the BODY element ("horizontal" depth).
    """
    ancestors = 0
    depth = element.tag_name
    if element.tag_name == "body":
        #print("Ancestors to root: {} ({}).".format(ancestors, depth))
        return ancestors
    while True:
        element = go_up(element)
        ancestors += 1
        depth = element.tag_name + " < " + depth
        if element.tag_name == "body":
            #print("Ancestors to root: {} ({}).".format(ancestors, depth))
            return ancestors
```

Putting it all together: compare all depths and return highest:

```
def maximum_depth(element, is_page=True):
    
    if is_page: # from body (pass drive as argument)
        depths = [ancestors_to_root(e) for e in element.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//body//*")]
    else: # from context node (pass an element)
        depths = [ancestors_to_root(e) for e in element.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//*")]
    if depths:
        all_depths = list(set(depths))
        print("Highest depth: ", max(all_depths))
    else:
        print("Highest depth: 0")
```

**Usage 1:** the whole page:

```
maximum_depth(drive)
```

**Usage 2:** depths within a specific element:

```
h3 = b.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[2]") # change to something in your page
maximum_depth(h3, is_page=False)
```

**Warning:** I tested *maximum_depth()* on a page with 579 nodes and a maximum depth of 19 and it took over 6 minutes to run.